# Pointer: p++ & p+1

Tags: c++, c, pointers

I am currently study pointer, but i have got few questions:

1. When we say `int a[] = {10, 11}; int *p = a`, the compiler would allocate memory for the pointer `p` (which points to the first address of the array). But if we say `p + 1`, does that mean that some memory has been initialized with a new pointer called `p + 1`?
2. If the answer to the above is negative, i.e. no  memory has been allocated for `p + 1`: When we use `*(p + 1)`, we still can get the value `11`. Does that mean that this symbol `*` can be used without a pointer (as long as we know the address)?

Comment: You talk about the memory doing things, that's not really how memory works. It becomes a bit hard to understand what you mean.

Comment: Could you also fix your code formatting a little bit?

Comment: 1. no. memory is allocated for a. p points to the beginning of a, p+1 points to a[1]. 2. * when applied to a pointer fetches the object pointed by the pointer, so in this case a[1]=11

Comment: @unwind I edited the question to express what I assume the user meant. Ruizhi: Please re-correct me if I assumed wrong.

Comment: When we say `int x = 5;` the compiler would allocate memory for the integer `x` (which holds the number 5). But if we say `x + 1`, does that mean that some memory has been initialized with a new integer called `x + 1`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, `*` can be used without a pointer variable, it's just an operator. It needs to be applied to an expression of a pointer type, but that expression doesn't have to be a single variable name.

For example:

```
int x = 42;

*(&x) = 4711;
```

The above sets `x` to `4711` using the `*` operator, but there's no separate pointer variable in the code. The type of the value returned by `&x` is of course `int *`, i.e. "pointer to integer", and that's a type that `*` can be used with.

The expression `p + 1` is just an expression, it can be evaluated and the result can be used (or thrown away, depending on the context). It's not "a pointer", although the resulting value is a pointer the expression itself is not.

Comment: thank you for your reply, does that mean: if I have a address, this address would be converted to pointer type(or addresses are pointer types)? Because you've said that * can be applied to an expression of a pointer type.... bit confusing, try to understand in an more deep level

Comment: Thank u so much , this helps me a lot

Comment: @Ruizhi The words "pointer" and "address" are usually used interchangeably.

Comment: @Ruizhi an "address" is really just a number used at machine instruction level. In typical C implementations, a pointer value is just the address of the thing it points to, but that's just an implementation detail.

Answer (score 2):

> 1)    when we say `int a[] = {10, 11}; int *p = a;`, the memory would allocate memory for pointer `p` (point to the first address of the array), but if we say `p + 1`, does that means that the memory has initiate a new pointer called `p + 1`?

Memory is 'allocated' (not necessarily from RAM) but it is not given a name - it is an unnamed temporary value. It may exist only in a `CPU` register.

> 2)   if the answer of above is negative, the memory doesn't allocate memory for `p + 1`, when we use `*(p + 1)`, we still can get the value `11`, does that mean that this symbol `*` can be used without pointer(as long as we know the address)?

A *temporary* pointer is created which `*(p + 1)` dereferences.

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume that there are declarations

```
int a[] = {10, 11};
int *p = a;
```

In this case variable `P` is initialized by the address of the first element of the array `a`.

To evaluate this expression

```
p + 1
```

the compiler gets the value stored in the pointer `p` and according to the pointer arithmetic adds to it the value of expression `sizeof( int )`. Thus the expression yields a new address that points to the memory after the first element of the array `a` that is the calculated value is the address of the second element of the array.

In fact the compiler can create a temporary object of type `int *` to store this intermediate value. But the lifetime of the object does not exceed the life-time of the expression itself.

You may apply operator `*` to expressions that have types of pointers.

Consider this code

```
int a[] = {10, 11};
int *p = a;

for ( size_t i = 0; i < sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a ); i++ ) 
{
    std::cout << *( p + i ) >> ' ';
}

std::cout << std::endl;
```

As for this expression

```
p++;
```

then there are two actions. The first one yields the value of the expression that is equal to the current value stored in p. The second one is equivalent to `p = p + 1;`.

Comment: I wonder if we should also mention that `*` is an operator that can be overloaded for a class.

Comment: @AndyG This operator is already overloaded because it can be used as a multiplicative operator.:)

Answer (score 1):

> the memory would allocate memory

The compiler would generate code that sets aside memory, rather. This happens when you declare `int* p;` and then use the variable `p` somewhere in your code. Regardless of how you use it.

> does that mean that this symbol * can be used without pointer(as long as we know the address)

This question doesn't make any sense. How exactly would you use `*` without a pointer operand?

Not quite sure what you want to do. To get the contents stored at a known address, you must have a pointer type and you must use the `*` operator.

So in theory you could do silly things like

```
*(int*)(0x12345678 + 1*sizeof(int))
```

or the equivalent

```
((int*)0x12345678)[1]
```

if you know that the array is stored at address 0x12345678. But in practice, you would never write such code, because it is ugly and the address may change.

Comment: Casting well-known address values to pointers is not really silly; it's actually indispensable in low-level (driver, CPU setup etc.) programs.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider No, not really. Such programs would have register map headers, where you will either get handed something that works as a variable or as a pointer. For example the map could hold a register definition like this `#define PORTX (*(volatile uint32_t*)0x12345678)`. That doesn't mean that the application program should run off and do such casts in the middle of the code... doing so would be silly and make the program unreadable. Rather, the application should use `PORTX` as if it was any plain 32 bit variable.

Comment: I didn't talk about program design; I just remarked (and we seem to agree on that point) that there are legitimate or even necessary use cases for casting an integer (literal) to a pointer. The inexperienced reader could miss that when reading your "silly" and "in theory".